How to Detect Magisk Hide with Zygisk and Enforce DenyList Enabled in an Android FinTech App?
I’m developing a FinTech Android app where detecting rooted devices is crucial for security reasons. I’ve implemented root detection using the RootBeer library, which successfully detects rooted devices in most cases. However, I’ve encountered a scenario where a device is rooted with Magisk, and the following advanced options are enabled:
Zygisk: A Magisk module that hides the root status by injecting into the Zygote process.
Magisk Hide (or Enforce DenyList in newer versions of Magisk): This feature hides the root status from apps.
With these options enabled, RootBeer fails to detect that the device is rooted. This poses a significant security risk for my app.
1.What are the best practices or methods to reliably detect root access on a device when Magisk Hide, Zygisk, and Enforce DenyList are enabled?
2.Are there any specific techniques, libraries, or additional checks I can implement to overcome these obfuscation techniques and ensure root detection?
3.How can I prevent my app from running on devices where these advanced root-hiding methods are active?

There is no reliable way to detect root access, it's a game of cat and mouse, a chase that never ends. While libraries like RootBeer can detect normal root, there are many powerful and effective bypass methods available, such as Frida.

Yes, you're right. I've searched extensively, but I haven't found a definitive solution for the same ,is there any correct way to detect  Frida or Magisk Hide?

can anyone help me to detect magisk hide?

@KaungKhantKyaw can you suggest any way to detect magisk hide or frida as for now so that my security team check app and give me sign off.

@PriyaKushwah any progress on it ? Looking for the same ... :/

@SourabhBans Not yet i have used rootbeer lib but that can not detect denylist.

@PriyaKushwah Do you have a setup with rooted mobile device and magisk with denylist to test any work around ?

@PriyaKushwah Try Google Play Integrity. https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview

@Sourabh Bans yes i have rooted emulator.and enabled magisk with denylist.

Like the comment already mentioned its a cat and mouse game one of the reason being you are in the userspace of the OS. Also welcome to the world of mobile security.
However there are few industry standards you can do, implementing a controls and maintaining it is hard, thats why paid solution is probably better. here are the answers for your question:

Ans: file-based detections, proc based detection etc. For both Magisk and Zygisk, but its best to buy a product since there are security researcher who look for new flavours of rooting and new control bypass techniques. Some of the vendors that provide RASP(Runtime application security program): Guardsquare, Appdome, Zimpirium etc.
Ans: Depends on the language you are writing it in, obfuscation is hiding/making it hard to reverse you application during static analysis. renaming obfuscation, control flow obfuscation, encryption obfuscation again it all depends on the language you are writing it in.
The best you can do is detect and crash, but again there are flavour of those advanced root-hiding. Magisk is just the start, there are other tools like that which give you much bigger control of the device and those aren't detected yet. Like KernelSu and Kpatch etc.

All in all if you really care about security and its a small team you would be best buying a product. Otherwise you would probably need to accept the risk
Edit: You would also probably want to start in this page: OWASP MSTG

Thank you for reply, Could you kindly provide any references or documentation related to file-based detection and proc-based detection for both Magisk and Zygisk, especially when an app is in the denylist? At this time, we are not  purchasing the product, but we would greatly appreciate any available resources.

I am not currently familiar with the specifics of file-based and proc-based detection methods. However, I am looking into this matter, and if I come across any relevant solutions or insights, I will be sure to share them with you. i am sharing a github link this might help you (https://github.com/aimardcr/AndroidNativeGuard).

To follow up on the play integrity part - I believe it's possible to fool play integrity too, so good luck.
But anyway, what's the point?
Do you assume that the immediate thought of person who got conned because of root access will be "o s**t, let me first remove the root and then I'll call my bank"?
People who root most likely know what they do. People who use Magisk know even more. People who use zygisk are most likely pros who will eventually find a way to bypass your protections.
Get over it.

It's probably not easy, but among the many FinTech(banking) apps on the market, there are apps that detect even though the latest magisk app hide denylist is applied. It's not that there's no way out.

Thank you @Ruffalo but how those banking apps doing this?

@PriyaKushwah It's probably because they paid for it and applied security solutions. That's how security is increased.

Thank you for your reply.I could not buy product but  I have downloaded the Play Integrity Checker(i.e https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gr.nikolasspyr.integritycheck&hl=en_IN) from the Play Store, and it detects the enforce list as well. I am planning to implement Play Integrity in my project.

@PriyaKushwah is there any way other than Play Integrity to detect from denylist?

@danial No i have not found other solution yet. i have tried NDK but denylist cannot detected.

You can explore the RASP solution offered by Bugsmirror (Bugsmirror Defender). It’s cost-effective and comes with a free trial.

@PriyaKushwah checking pm commands & pm conventional APIs worked for me

@danial Thank you can you provide any refernce or source code for the same?
